# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed 4 times

Tags: arrays, angular, dropdown

I have 4 dropdowns 
 -FromYear-
 -FromMonth-
 -ToYear-
 -ToMonth-
When I select an year from 1st and 3rd dropdown, it should get an array of months to populate my other dropdowns.
 I get my months with selected year's id using selectFromYearsEvent

This is my Component

```
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  year: number[];

  selectYears: Year[];

  selectedFromYear: Year;
  selectedToYear: Year;

  selectFromMonths: Month[];
  selectToMonths: Month[];

  selectedFromMonth: Month;
  selectedToMonth: Month;

  selectedMonths: Month[];

  months: Month[];

  constructor(private calendarService: CalendarService, private monthsService: MonthsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.getYears();
      }

  getYears() {
    this.calendarService.getYears().subscribe(y => {
      this.selectYears = y;
    });
  }

  getMonth() {
    this.calendarService.getYear(this.selectedFromYear.id).subscribe(y => {
      this.selectedFromYear.months = y;
      this.selectFromMonths = y;
    });
  }

  selectFromYearsEvent(newYear) {
    this.selectedFromYear = newYear;
    this.getMonth();

  }
}
```

and this is my HTML code

```
<div class="container-calendar">
        <div class="calendar-dates">
        <!-- from part -->
        <div class="from-date">
          <div class="from-date-dropdown">
            <select name="fromYear" [(ngModel)]="selectYears" (ngModelChange)="selectFromYearsEvent($event)">      <!-- [(ngModel)]="selectedFromYear"> -->
              <option name="fromYear2" *ngFor="let year of selectYears" [ngValue]="year">                   
                  {{year.number}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="from-date">
          <div class="state-dropdown">
            <select name="fromMonth" [(ngModel)]="selectFromMonths" (ngModelChange)="selectFromMonthEvent($event)"> <!-- [(ngModel)]="selectedFromMonth"> -->
              <option *ngFor='let month of selectFromMonth' [ngValue]="month"> 
                  {{month.name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `*ngFor` requires an array, are you positive the data you're receiving is an array and not an array wrapped in an object or anything else? The error you're getting makes it seem as though you're getting an object back, not an array.

Comment: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{name: "Jan", number: 1}
1
:
{name: "Feb", number: 2}
2
:
{name: "März", number: 3}
3
:
{name: "April", number: 4}
4
:
{name: "Mai", number: 5}
5
:
{name: "Juni", number: 6}
6
:
{name: "Juli", number: 7}
7
:
{name: "Aug", number: 8}
8
:
{name: "Sep", number: 9}
9
:
{name: "Okt", number: 10}
10
:
{name: "Nov", number: 11}
11
:
{name: "Dez", number: 12}
length
:
12
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: @Narm, what do you think?

Comment: If that is the data in your response then it does look like you're getting an array of objects. Could you create a [mcve] in StackBlitz?

Comment: `<option *ngFor='let month of selectFromMonth' [ngValue]="month"> ` This may be your offending line. It looks like from your code `selectedFromMonth` is going to be an object like `{name: "April", number: 4}` which is just a plain object so you won't be able to iterate over it with the `*ngFor`.